# Calendar Provider with Android API 24+ "The requested event was not found"

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

I'm adding events to a **local calendar**, this works fine with API < 24 (KitKat, Lollipop, Marshmallow), but I get issues with Google Calendar not able to open the events from my local calendar and returning "The requested event was not found"

Events **are listed** into Google Calendar, but cannot be opened, edited or deleted

Code to create the local calendar:

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, "My Calendar");
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, "My Calendar");
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, BLACK_COLOR);

Uri updateUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
updateUri.buildUpon()
.appendQueryParameter(android.provider.CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "false")
.build();

Uri uri = cr.insert(updateUri, values);
```

Code to create an event into the calendar:

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, start);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, end);    
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID); // CalID = My Calendar Id
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "Australia/Sydney");

Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an account name CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME and an account type in the ContentValues when you are creating the calendar